assembly.adaptive.xsd referenced but missing in ClickOnce Deployment
I'm deploying an application with ClickOnce and it is working fine.
But after creating the deployment I get a warning from visual studio: "Could not find file"..."assembly.adaptive.xsd"
That file is referenced in the auto generated MyApplication.application
The first two lines of MyApplication.application:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">

Any idea what this file is for, where I can download or generate it? Or how do I change settings that the click once builder does not reference it.
I searched my whole drive for the file but didn't find it. Nor did I find the file online (only references to it)
